# Pointer Content was deleted after function call, why?

Tags: c, pointers, memory

I've been trying to figure out what's going on with my code, but no luck. I have defined a pointer:
    char ** filesList = readDir();
The pointer is pointing to an array of Strings. I was able to have all filenames in the current directory. That's not the issue.

When I pass filesList[i], for any i=0,..,n :
    readImage(filesList[i],...);
the content of filesList is erased.. I don't know why.. Any help?!

My code:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <syslog.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <dirent.h>

#include <jpeglib.h>

unsigned char *readImage(//struct jpeg_decompress_struct cinfo,
                         char *inputPath,
                         int *width,
                         int *height,
                         int *pixel_size)
{
    char *inputFilename;
    struct jpeg_decompress_struct cinfo;
    unsigned char *buffer;
    int rc, i, j;
    struct stat file_info;
    unsigned long jpg_size;
    unsigned char *jpg_buffer;

    struct jpeg_error_mgr jerr;
    int row_stride;

    inputFilename = (char *)malloc(1 + strlen(inputPath));
    strcpy(inputFilename, inputPath);

    rc = stat(inputFilename, &file_info);
    if (rc) {
        syslog(LOG_ERR, "FAILED to stat source jpg");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    jpg_size = file_info.st_size;
    jpg_buffer = (unsigned char*) malloc(jpg_size + 100);

    int fd = open(inputFilename, O_RDONLY);
    i = 0;
    while (i < jpg_size) {
        rc = read(fd, jpg_buffer + i, jpg_size - i);
        i += rc;
    }
    close(fd);

    cinfo.err = jpeg_std_error(&jerr);

    jpeg_create_decompress(&cinfo); // <-- Exactly at this point, inputPath's content is erased ...

    jpeg_mem_src(&cinfo, jpg_buffer, jpg_size);

    rc = jpeg_read_header(&cinfo, TRUE);

    if (rc != 1) {
        syslog(LOG_ERR, "File does not seem to be a normal JPEG");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    jpeg_start_decompress(&cinfo);
    *width = cinfo.output_width;
    *height = cinfo.output_height;
    *pixel_size = cinfo.output_components;

    unsigned long bmp_size = cinfo.output_width * cinfo.output_height * cinfo.output_components;
    buffer = (unsigned char*)malloc(bmp_size);

    row_stride = cinfo.output_width * cinfo.output_components;

    while (cinfo.output_scanline < cinfo.output_height) {
        unsigned char *buffer_array[1];
        buffer_array[0] = buffer + (cinfo.output_scanline) * row_stride;

        jpeg_read_scanlines(&cinfo, buffer_array, 1);
    }

    jpeg_finish_decompress(&cinfo);
    jpeg_destroy_decompress(&cinfo);
    free(jpg_buffer);

    return buffer;
}

char **readDir(int *nof) {
    char **filesList;
    int numFiles = 0;
    int size = 256;
    DIR *d;
    struct dirent *dir;

    d = opendir(".");
    if (d) {
        filesList = (char **)malloc(size);
        while ((dir = readdir(d)) != NULL) {
            if (strstr(dir->d_name, ".jpeg")) {
                printf("%s\n", dir->d_name);
                filesList[numFiles] = (char *)malloc(256);
                filesList[numFiles++] = dir->d_name;
                size += 256;
                filesList = realloc(filesList, size);
            }
        }
        closedir(d);
    }
    *nof = numFiles;
    return filesList;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    unsigned char *buffer;
    char **filesList;
    int numberOfFiles;
    int width;
    int height;
    int pixel_size;
    int i;

    filesList = readDir(&numberOfFiles);

    for (i = 0; i < numberOfFiles; ++i) {
        printf("file: %s\n", filesList[i]); // <-- Here prints nothing in the second round

        buffer = readImage(filesList[i],
                           &width,
                           &height,
                           &pixel_size);
    }
    //free(temp);
    free(filesList);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Check this:

```
 jpeg_create_decompress(&cinfo); // <-- Exactly at this point, inputPath's content is erased ...
 // After this point, All filenames are erased
```

If you want to run the code, download the library jpeglib 8c
then, export the folder's path to PATH & C_INCLUDE_PATH
then, compile with:

```
gcc file.c -ljpeg
```

Comment: TL;DR. And format & indent a [mcve]!

Comment: I tried to create as minimal example as I can, but I couldn't regenerate the bug. So I posted my whole method with some initialization. I hope you guys understand.

Comment: 'filesList[numFiles++] = dir->d_name;' - should you not be copying that char array, instead of just assigning the pointer?

Comment: Also, this 'size += 256;' looks wrong.  If anything you should be increasing size by sizeof(char*), no?  Since size started off at 256, there would be no reason to increase it until all 256 bytes were full of pointers.

Comment: C does not support _methods_, what do you mean? Also don't cast the result of `malloc` & friends in C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The directory enumeration function is incorrect:

- You allocate memory for the directory entry, but then instead of copying the string into that, you overwrite the pointer you just allocated with `dir->d_name`, whose contents may get clobbered by further `readdir` calls.
- Your allocation scheme is imprecise and will fail for very long filenames.

Here is a corrected version:

```
char **readDir(int *nof) {
    char **filesList = NULL;
    int numFiles = 0;
    DIR *d;
    struct dirent *dir;

    d = opendir(".");
    if (d) {
        while ((dir = readdir(d)) != NULL) {
            if (strstr(dir->d_name, ".jpeg")) {
                printf("%s\n", dir->d_name);
                filesList = realloc(filesList, (numFiles + 1) * sizeof(char*));
                filesList[numFiles++] = strdup(dir->d_name);
            }
        }
        closedir(d);
    }
    *nof = numFiles;
    return filesList;
}
```

Note that `readDir()` should take the path as an argument, and `strstr` is not a precise way to match fie extensions: `list.jpeg.txt` will be mistakenly included in the list.

Comment: That look more like it, yes.

Comment: Thhhhhhhaaaaannnnnxxxxx

That really helped me. You are genius!